# keycloak.authenticated is alway false even after successful login in @react-keycloak/web

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, keycloak-js

I have a very simple react app and I want to add keycloak authentication to it's pages. I'm using following versions

- react v18
- keycloak 18.0.0 (with quarkus)
- react-keycloak/web: 3.4.0
- keycloak-js: 20.0.3
- react-router-dom: 6.8.1

These are my classes

**index.tsx**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  // <React.StrictMode>      
    <App />
  // </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

**App.tsx**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./pages/Homepage";
import keycloak from "./Keycloak"
import { ReactKeycloakProvider } from "@react-keycloak/web";
import './App.css';

function App() {

  return (
    <ReactKeycloakProvider authClient={keycloak} initOptions={{ onLoad: "login-required" }}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ReactKeycloakProvider>

  );
}

export default App;
```

**Keycloak configs**

```
import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";
const keycloak = new Keycloak({
url: "http://localhost:8180",
realm: "Demo",
clientId: "react-app",
});

export default keycloak;
```

**HomePage.tsx**

```
import { useKeycloak } from "@react-keycloak/web";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";


const Home = () => {

  const { keycloak } = useKeycloak();
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false)

  useEffect(()=>{
      setIsLoggedIn(keycloak.authenticated || false)
  }, [keycloak])    
  
  console.log("-----------is logged in:", isLoggedIn)

  return isLoggedIn ?  <h1 className="text-green-800 text-4xl">Welcome</h1> 
                      : <div>{`User is NOT authenticated`}</div>;


};

export default Home;
```

After I **npm start** and go to home page even I get keycloak login page.
[image]

But after login with correct credentials following page is shown. This page is shown when keycloak.authenticated is false.
[image]

**Console output**
[image]

I really appreciate if anyone can figure out why I'm not authenticated even after successful login.

github url: https://github.com/ruchiranawarathna/react-with-keycloak-auth

Comment: I posted this solution, hope it helps you.https://stackoverflow.com/a/77925275/1794262

Answer (score 0):

try making the access public by going to client details -> Capability config then turn off Client authentication and turn on Standard flow

Answer (score 0):

change the object passed to the Keycloak constructor to have these parameters

```
{
  "realm": "Your realm name",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8081/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "client name here",
  "public-client": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

OR you can as well click on `Download adapter config` from the `action` buttton dropdown in this screenshot and use the generated json object

[image]