# Keycloak-js returns authenticated false after successful login

Tags: javascript, keycloak

I have a simple frontend page which calls some backend service and I have a keycloak configured. In keycloak ui I configured a user, realm etc. I also configured nginx/openresty to secure my frontend page and it works as expected - when I go to this page I first get redirected to keycloak login page, I enter my login and password and successfully get redirected to frontend page. So, in terms of securing my frontend page everything works as expected. The frontend page is available at this endpoint:

```
https://localhost:8243/
```

And keycloak is available under this link:

```
https://localhost:8443/
```

I then try to use `keycloak-js` on my frontend page to check, that the user is indeed authenticated. I do it like so:

```
const keycloak = new Keycloak({
    url: 'https://localhost:8443/auth',
    authServerUrl: 'https://localhost:8443/auth',
    realm: 'testrealm',
    clientId: 'testuser'
});
keycloak.init().success(function (authenticated) {
    console.log("success => ", authenticated);
}).error(function () {
    console.log("error =>> ", keycloak);
});
```

But as a result I see this in console:

```
success => false
```

So, `keycloak-js` does not see, that the user is authenticated. What is wrong with that and how can I fix it? (PS. realm and clientId are totally correct)

UPDATE

In docs I see this information:

> To use the adapter, create a client for your application in the Keycloak Admin Console. Make the client public by toggling Client authentication to Off on the Capability config page.

But I do not quite understand the idea behind this. Should I create some new client just for using the adapter and what client should I then inject into `clientId`?

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue, resolved it by setting microprofile-jwt to "default" in the client scope page on keycloak admin.[image]